# Can not editing fusion table

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I am developing a component for joomla but I can edit anymore my tables I really dont know why. I have a user that is an owner and a user that is an editor. I log on to both of my accounts and I can't change, add or delete anything.  The only thing I can do from my owner account is change the type of share.
I dont know what happened.

Answer (score 0):

It got fixed after I took all the share privileges and re state them.